# Deleting model instance on save if field in model is null

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a model called Services. Upon the user saving the model form, I'd like the model instance to be deleted if the body is `null`. Here is my model:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Services, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.body == None:  #also tried if bool(self.body) == False:
            self.delete()
        else:
            pass
```

This code is not successful at deleting the model instance when body is `null` (or `blank`). Do you know where I've gone wrong?

Edit: I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Services)
def delete_services(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if bool(instance.body) == False:
        instance.delete()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `body` is blank you should test for `self.body == ''` rather than `self.body == None`.

You can test both together by simply writing `if not self.body:` instead.

Comment: Strange.. Can you print a debugging message before `self.delete()` to see if the test is successful or not?

Comment: added 
        print("Hi there") above 
        if not self.body:  
Nothing prints. I should note that I'm trying to do this with a model formset (i.e. I have 5 forms on one page, each corresponds to a model that has been created).